# Is it possible to access the "Reporting Services\ReportManager\Web.config" file directly from a report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to read an `appSettings` value from the `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.4\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Web.config` file and display it in a report.

I added a reference to `System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` and set field `Value` property to
`System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SomeKey")`.

All I got is an ultra-useful `#Error` message.

---

I found the [Can you reference appSettings in an SSRS report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226607/can-you-reference-appsettings-in-an-ssrs-report) question, but I'd like to avoid creating a custom assembly if possible (after all, what I want to do, requires no custom logic).

---

Bonus question:

- How can I troubleshoot this problem? Where can I find more
  detailed information about error
  that occured? (I checked the files
  in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL.4\Reporting
  Services\LogFiles` and Event Viewer - there's nothing there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work (with the help of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/config_file_and_assembly.aspx))!
It turned out that I was doing everything *almost* right from the beginning - I only had to change small details:

1. I moved `appSettings` to the
   `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\MSSQL.4\Reporting
   Services\ReportServer\web.config` file
   (all attempts to access
   `ReportManager\Web.config` failed).
2. I replaced the `System.Web`
   reference with
   `System.Configuration,
   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.
3. I used
   `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SomeKey")`
   to read the value.

Comment: Hi @Marek, I have same issue now. I didnt get the 2 nd point. What do you mean by replacing the System.Web with System.Configuration ?.

Comment: @MustangManiac Initially I tried to use `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` (see the question for its assembly). That did not work, so I replaced it with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` (see the answer and you'll see I referenced a different assembly).

Comment: thanks for your quick response @marek. I have been trying the procedure but unfortunately it is not working for me. it still throwing an error like connectionstring is invalid from ssrs

Comment: im trying to pass a connection string to the custom code from Web.config;  until now 1) i added system.configuration refernce to the custom code   2) i added the appsettings to the web.config on the ReportServer folder from C drive

Comment: im using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connectionstring") ; to pass the connection string, after using the above line it is throwing an invalid connection string error

Comment: Is it possible to pass the connection string to Custom code(SSRS) by using web.config ? or is there any chance to grab the connection string from shared datasource?

Comment: I don't know about the latter, the former should work. When you debug your code, is it fetching the connection string properly? Can you post this connection string? I suggest you add all these details to *your* question.

Comment: No,it is not fetching the connection string, that is what the issue . and while debugging it is throwing "connectionstring is invalid" error

Comment: Unless you post the code and appropriate piece of the web.config file, I won't be able to guess what may be wrong.